# What is the correct placement and permissions of .ssh and authorized_key for Ansible's use on a Windows target?

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, ansible, windows-10

[You'd think with all the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/windows_setup.html#win32-openssh-authentication) I'd have Ansible down pat by now.

My OpenSSH-Win64 is installed in C:\Program Files\OpenSSH-Win64
[As prescribed here](https://www.hostwinds.com/guide/how-to-install-and-configure-openssh-windows-server-2016/).

Windows target sshd responds to and accepts remote login to a local account with the local account password.

[install-sshd.ps1 installs](https://www.hostwinds.com/guide/how-to-install-and-configure-openssh-windows-server-2016/):

```
C:\ProgramData\ssh
```

and I set Win target sshd_config:

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

and I copied the contents of the ansible_test_id_rsa.pub I generated on the Ansible host into:

```
C:\Users\localadmin\.ssh\authorized_keys
```

but then I found this I never saw before in sshd_config:

```
Match Group administrators
       AuthorizedKeysFile __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys
```

So, reacting to that I then added the pub key contents into administrators_authorized_keys and set the access to SYSTEM and Administrators only.

But my:

```
ansible -u user all -m ping
```

still results in:

```
hostname | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: user@hostname: Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

How do you have a these files placed, populated and permissions set?

Answer (score 1):

another reason this could be failing, it did for me anyway, was that I had another language install ( German ) of windows and the openssh group match line matches administrators using the text string administrators. BUT in German MS use administratoren instead. ;-(

English: ( current shipping default )

```
Match Group administratoren
  AuthorizedKeysFile __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys
```

German:

```
Match Group administratoren
  AuthorizedKeysFile __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys
```

Instead of this insanity. Please change the current Match rule to something like this:

```
Match Group *S-1-5-32-544
  AuthorizedKeysFile __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys
```

They really should allow use of SIDs for this and also even more importantly for the DenyGroups matching.

If they only use text string matching there too, then this is a security hole as using a different language windows install will circumvent the intended 'deny'.